# Autocompletion in "Scala IDE(4.7-x) with Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0)" does NOT work

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I have installed plugin Scala IDE 4.7.x in my Eclipse Version 4.10.0 (2018-12). When I try to auto-complete Scala Code(using CTRL+SPACE), it gives me the following the error message.

I tried disabling Java related proposals from content assist assist from Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->ContentAssist->Advacned. That did not work. Please have a look at the screenshot below:

[image: ScalaIDE Error Message]

Comment: Looks like that version of the Scala IDE is not compatible with Eclipse 2018-12 because it is trying to use an internal class which has changed.

Comment: I would ask on the gitter channel, someone made an update available, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Some progress on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

ran into the same problem with Eclipse 2019-03 and this is a bug in Eclipse, it is fixed in Eclipse 2019-06.

you can already update to the RC1 with using the P2 URL :
https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/2019-06/Simultaneous_Release_Plan#p2_Repository

Final Release will arrive in a week.

see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698535/4473413