# Error in Eclipse with Scala IDE autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, scala

Auto-complete (ctrl-space) fails in Eclipse with Scala IDE with the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>
(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/JavaProject;
Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/WorkingCopyOwner;)V
```

How can I fix this?

Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Scala IDE version: 4.7.0 with Scala up to 2.12 installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK turns out this is a silly oversight on my part.

There was a breaking change in the constructor for `SearchableEnvironment`, where an additional argument was added.  The latest Scala IDE is based on Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen), and will not work with 4.10 / 2018-12 because of this.

Running Scala IDE with Eclipse 4.7 works now.

Comment: didn't understand your answer about the broken constructor. My understanding is that the latest Scala IDE runs on oxygen and newer.

Comment: No, the problem was that there was a breaking change in the underlying Eclipse JDT libraries such that Scala IDE would break on a newer Eclipse.

Comment: it's technically a bug if they don't keep a constructor with the original signature for backward compatibility. Should be simple for the eclipse group to fix

Answer (score 2):

this issue with the autocomplete is resolved in the upcoming version of Eclipse 2019-06! The fix is currently merged into the 4.12M1 milestone.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546156

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release

Comment: just updated Eclipse 2019-03 to 2019-06 RC1, and now Scala autocompletion works like a charm.

updated with : https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/2019-06/Simultaneous_Release_Plan#p2_Repository